# Batch reading only certain variables of many files

Tags: r

I have one different CSV file for every month since 2010. They all have the same basic information, but recent files have more variables than the old ones. They are also arranged in different orders.

I want to batch read all the files in my directory as data.tables, select a list of variables from each read file and then compile them into a longitudinal data.table unsing `rbind`.

I thought of using something along the lines of:

```
all_files = list.files()
dbs <- lapply(all_files, data.table)
```

Then select a list of variables from each `data.table`:

```
object[ , c("ID", "Date", "Paid", "Pending")]
# These 4 variables have the exact same names throughout all files.
```

And finally, use `rbind` to bind all the data.tables together.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look at the docs for `?fread` and `?rbindlist`, it should take you close to what you're after, I think.

Comment: If the column names of your csv files are consistent i.e. the same variable is named identically in both old and new files, it should be fairly easy to implement. If not, you can still have a simple logic to identify if it's a 'new' or 'old' format and read columns accordingly.

Comment: @Gautam Yes, all the variables are named identically in all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns are named identically:

```
library(data.table) 
fnames <- dir(path = choose.dir(), pattern = '.*csv', full.names = T, recursive = F)
cols <- c('ID', 'Date', 'Paid', 'Pending')
data_list <- lapply(fnames, function(z){
  ret <- fread(z, select = cols)
  ret$filename <- z
  return(ret)
})
```

I stored `filename` as a column name because you may want to trace back where the data came from (for any discrepancies etc.).

To get it into a single `data.table` object:

```
dat <- rbindlist(dat_list, use.names = T, fill = T)
```

Comment: Tank you so much @Gautam!
Worked perfectly.